# Shadow table for rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audit-tables

I have Follow model in my rails app and when user follow some content - record created, unfollow - record deleted.

I need track this changes in separate table (insert and delete only).

It will be used to build some reports with plain SQL - thats why table should have similar structure aka "shadow"

I don't want polute original model with additional logic - 
there is some solutions but they don't flexible enough:

**https://github.com/rubiety/has_draft** - I can't select specific operations

**https://github.com/bglusman/ruby-shadow-tables** - raw and mysql only

Does anybody know some good solution for such case?

Comment: try https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail

Comment: it serialize data and put everything to one table I need separate table

Answer (score 0):

You can create one more table shadow_follows and have a callback method after_create and before_destroy to copy the target record to new table.

Comment: Yeah I think about thats but it looks like functionality which can be delegated to gem

Comment: https://rubygems.org/gems/audited gem is there but it wont create replica of the table; though you can specify which all tables can be audited.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any suitable gem for such case and decide implement it with rails observer. nothing special.. just simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly old, but in case someone else wants to do something like this, a friend and I did a script to set up shadow tables in rails with DB triggers...  https://github.com/bglusman/ruby-shadow-tables

It's a bit crufty, and would definitely benefit from being abstracted into a gem, and perhaps a DB neutral solution.